# How Does localStorage in HTML5 work?

Tags: javascript, web-applications, local-storage

How Does `localStorage` in HTML5 work? I searched every where (even in **SO** ) to find the actual **internal logic** of localStorage, but I ended up with visiting some examples which uses localStorage. I haven't found any useful Answer to my question. Can Someone post me a link or explain about the working of `localStorage`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not necessarily sure what you're looking for here...but the internal implementation of `localStorage` is going to be browser specific. I wouldn't count on any two browsers implementing the feature the same way internally (just like everything, the implementation and performance will give each browser a different advantage).

If you're really interested, I'd suggest pulling down the Chromium source and seeing how they implement things internally.

Comment: Or view the Firefox implementation at http://hg.mozilla.org/releases/mozilla-1.9.2/file/b2da18a3f256/storage/src

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple jQuery plugin for store information using localStorage or cookie.
This plugin it's useful because you don't need control if the browser has or hasn't suport to localStorage.

https://github.com/thyagoquintas/jquery-storage