# How can I store a selected radio button's text in localStorage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Can anyone help me how to set the radio button selected text in localStorage? Here is my code but I'm getting undefined value at every time:

```
<label for="gender">GENDER:  
<input type="radio" id="radiobtn1" name="gender" value="0"/>  
<label for="radiobtn1">MALE</label>  
<input type="radio" id="radiobtn1" name="gender" value="1"/>
<label for="radiobtn1">FEMALE</label>  
</label> 
<br>
```

jQuery code; I'm getting selected value when trying to write the code like this:

```
var tempgender = $("input:checked + label").text(); 
console.log("gender selcte value:" + tempgender);
```

But when trying to save selected value in localstorage by writing this code then getting "undefined value".

```
window.localStorage.setItem("tempgender",$("input:checked + label").text());`
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please don't ask another question until you've learned to use the editor. That was one of the most poorly formatted posts I've seen in three years.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3628265/localstorage-in-html5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

code is correct but i think localstorage is not supported by your browser , do perform before using localstorage

```
if(typeof(Storage)!=="undefined")
{
  alert("storage is supported and you can store data in it");
}
else
{
 alert("Get new version of browser or use browser which support storage");
}
```

for further details you can check : [**Store data locally with HTML5 Web Storage**](http://pranayamr.blogspot.in/2013/03/store-data-locally-with-html5-web.html)